# Create new grammar xml for UWP

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I'm trying to create my personal grammar for Microsoft Speech Recognition.

this is what I have done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <grammar
  version="1.0" mode="voice" root="commands"
  xml:lang="en-EN" tag-format="semantics/1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">

 <rule id="commands">
  <one-of>
   <item>
    <ruleref uri="#open"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ruleref uri="#areas"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ruleref uri="#zones"/>
  </item>
</one-of>
```

My open rule is simply:

```
<rule id="open">
 <one-of>
    <item>
        <one-of>
            <item>open</item>
        </one-of>
        <tag> out="open"; </tag>
    </item>
 </one-of>
</rule>
```

Now I would like to create a new rule that involves the two main rules *zones* and *areas*. So, basically, I would like to say "zone 1 area 5" (so the keyword zone and area with a number) and the Speech Recognitions is able to understand the entire phrase "zone 1 area 5". Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: I forgot to say that you can say: **1)** the only open command **2)** the zone + number + area + number command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a sample:

```
    <rule id="commands" scope="public">      
        <one-of>
            <item><ruleref uri="#open" /></item>
            <item><tag>out.result=""; </tag> <ruleref uri="#zonearea" /> <tag> out.result=rules.latest();</tag> </item>         
    </one-of>
  </rule>

  <rule id="open">
        <one-of>
        <item>
        <one-of>
            <item>open</item>
        </one-of>
        <tag> out="open"; </tag>
        </item>
        </one-of>
    </rule>

    <rule id="zonearea" scope="private">
        <item> ZONE </item>
        <item>
            <ruleref uri="#Number"/><tag> out = "ZONE " +rules.Number; </tag>
        </item>
        <item> AREA </item>
        <item>
            <ruleref uri="#Number"/>
            <tag> out = " AREA " + rules.latest();</tag>
        </item>
    </rule>

    <rule id="Number" scope = "private">
        <one-of>
        <item> one <tag> out ="1"; </tag></item>
      <item> two <tag> out ="2"; </tag></item>
      <item> three <tag> out ="3"; </tag></item> 
        </one-of>
    </rule>
```

Comment: Hi Frenchy, thanks for your answer....one thing... the line <item><tag>out.result="";  is referred to  open rule?? because I don't understand why the tag item is there

Comment: Furthermore, I obtain a grammar compilation error with this grammar

Comment: Ok I found the problem....in <rule id="#zonearea" scope="private"> you have to delete # in the rule name